KEDA SQL Server trigger can't login to SQL Server DB on Azure using Azure Service Principal
We are trying to use SQL Server trigger for scaling application and trying to authenticate the SQL DB using Azure Service Principle. But no luck. We are keeping connection string in Kubernetes Secret and trying to use this. but no luck. Getting login failed error like

ERROR mssql_scaler Found error pinging mssql: mssql: login error: Login failed for user xxxxxxxxx

But application able to access DB using same connection string. Any solution or work around for this?
But every thing is working fine when we are using SQL Authentication instead of service principal.
Below is the connection string format we are using
kubectl create secret generic my-mssql-secrets --from-literal mssql-connection-string="server=azuse2sqlmixxxxx.xxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;Initial Catalog=yyyyyy;User Id=99775ec3-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx;Password=xxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"\*\*

Keda Meta Data Details  -
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
name: keda-trigger-auth-mssql-secret
spec:
secretTargetRef:

parameter: connectionString
name: my-mssql-secrets
key: mssql-connection-string


apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
name: mssql-scaledobject
spec:
minReplicaCount: 1
maxReplicaCount: 10
scaleTargetRef:
name: app-MyApplicationName
triggers:

type: mssql
metadata:
targetValue: "{{ .Values.kedaTargetValue }}"
query: "{{ .Values.kedaQuery }}"
authenticationRef:
name: keda-trigger-auth-mssql-secret

Please help here if you have any solution or work around.
Below is the connection string format we are using -
**
kubectl create secret generic my-mssql-secrets --from-literal mssql-connection-string="server=azuse2sqlmixxxxx.xxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;Initial Catalog=yyyyyy;User Id=99775ec3-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx;Password=xxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"**
Keda Meta Data Details  -
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
name: keda-trigger-auth-mssql-secret
spec:
secretTargetRef:

parameter: connectionString
name: my-mssql-secrets
key: mssql-connection-string


apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
name: mssql-scaledobject
spec:
minReplicaCount: 1
maxReplicaCount: 10
scaleTargetRef:
name: app-MyApplicationName
triggers:

type: mssql
metadata:
targetValue: "{{ .Values.kedaTargetValue }}"
query: "{{ .Values.kedaQuery }}"
authenticationRef:
name: keda-trigger-auth-mssql-secret


Hi @Rukmini,
Thanks for your comments. The Service Principal has enough permission for DB access. This Service Principal is working fine from application.


ERROR mssql_scaler Found error pinging mssql: mssql: login error: Login failed for user xxxxxxxxx

As per this MS document, if the user is not valid in the database or if the user is not the AAD Server Admin, you may get the above error while connecting to the database. to resolve the error login to the Azure SQL server with administrator, create user of service principle to the database and assign role to the user using below query:
create user [<appName>] from external provider;
alter role db_datareader add member [<appName>];
alter role db_datawriter add member [<appName>];



Alternatively, you can set the service principle as SQL server admin as shown below:

You can use below connection string:
server=<serverName>.database.windows.net;
Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;
Initial Catalog=yyyyyy;
User Id=<clientId>;
Password=<password>;
TenantId=<tenantId>;
Persist Security Info=False;
Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=True;

Alternatively, you can use Managed Identity authentication, if you want to use password less connection to connect to the Azure SQL database. Enable workload identities in the AKS cluster to use this. For more information you can refer to the similar thread in SO.

I tried with above connection string format but no luck. Need to change any keda meta dada ??

KEDA (Kubernetes Event-driven Autoscaling) doesn't require login or connection changes but needs proper role assignments for its Managed Identity/service principle. Ensure the Kubernetes cluster/server has Managed Identity enabled, and assign appropriate roles (e.g., Azure Service Bus Data Receiver) to allow KEDA to access required Azure resources.

The AKS able to access AKV using same service principal and able to access DB instance no network error. We are getting Login error.. due to Auth param.
ERROR   scale_handler   error resolving auth params     {"type": "ScaledObject", "namespace": "test", "name": "mssql-scaledobject", "triggerIndex": 0, "error": "error establishing mssql connection: mssql: login error: Login failed for user '99775ec3-3a70-4db7-*********'."}
